# How do you force a specific dependency version?

Tags: node.js, npm

How do I safely enforce an npm dependency version across all packages? I have a package that's pulling an older version of a dependency and I'd like to patch it (and all other packages) to use the latest one?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question. So i am answering again.

To update all npm packages you can do as in the example below:

```
npm update

changed 17 packages, and audited 690 packages in 2m

91 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

However i executed that on a verify recent nestjs installation.

Updating an old project can generate several issues.

1. you cant be sure that interactive dependency works in a newer version between them. Means it can even happen that a certain module cant be used anymore and must be substituted with something else.
2. Often you will get into breaking code changes. So you have to refactor the code for each of them.

Comment: Sorry, this forces all dependencies to use 2.3.1?

Comment: No. It saves that package at that version.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question, and got in only now. I answered again. Maybe it can help you.